# How can I separate pages with Vim?

Tags: vim

I have the requirement of separating an ASCII document into pages of max length 58 lines per page. At the bottom of each page there is a 3 line footer. I'm not aware of any pagination abilities within Vim that would accomplish this.

Is there a good way to do this with Vim? Perhaps highlighting every 58th line or something of the sort.

N.B. I'm seeing answers involving using a separate tool to do this; which I have thought of. What I'm interested in is a Vim solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure; you could write a macro that did the equivalent of `while (1) do { 58j; rfooter.txt }`, but this is slower than any of the other solutions presented to you here. Perhaps if you explained why you wanted a vim solution? Not every hammer-like object has to be applied to everything that looks nailish... at least not without a bounty applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible in vim as a script. Put the following in a file and `:source` it while the file to change is open. The s:footer list are the lines to insert after each run of 58 lines.

```
let s:footer = ["","Footer",""]
let s:line = 0

while s:line <= line("$") - 58
  let s:line = s:line + 58
  call append(s:line, s:footer)
  let s:line = s:line + len(s:footer)
endwhile
```

Comment: I guess this is the best Vim only solution. It would be nice if there was some native way to do this.

Comment: You could also make this into a function and command (optionally in a plugin) with an argument for the number of lines.  Then it becomes a simple case of typing `:Paginate 58` or something like that.  If you want to be REALLY clever, you could automatically remove the old footers and re-add them (as long as there's no risk of matching text in the body of your document).

Answer (score 3):

The proper tool you're looking for is very likely a2ps.

```
a2ps --lines-per-page 58 --footer=footer_text document.txt
```

Comment: Good answer but I want to know if Vim can be used for this.

Answer (score 2):

Why is it important to use vim? You could use `split` and `cat` more efficiently.

Assuming your original file is called `file` and you have a file, `footer`, created that includes your footer text.

```
$ split -l 58 file file_parts
$ for i in file_parts*; do cat $i footer > $i.footered; done
$ cat file_parts*.footered > file.footered
```

`file.footered` would have your original file with the contents of `footer` inserted at every 58th line.

This is assuming you want it all back in the original file. If you don't, then the resulting file_parts*.footered files would be the already separated pages so you could skip the last step.

Answer (score 2):

The two most effective ways for doing that in Vim are a script (like
@Geoff has already suggested) and a substitution command, like

```
:%s@\%(.*\n\)\{58}@\0---\rfooter\r---\r@
```

A macro (as suggested in a comment to the question) is the slowest,
a script is the fastest. A substitution command is slower than script,
but much faster than a macro.

So probably substitution is the best Vim-only solution unless its
performance is unacceptable. Only in that case, I think, it is worth
writing a script.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to use the wrong tool for this. You could do it much easier programmatically, for example with this simple Perl oneliner:

```
perl -pe'print "your\nfooter\nhere\n" unless $. % 58' inputfilename > outputfilename
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive macro might work. Experiment with the following (position the cursor on the first character of the first line and switch to normal mode):

```
qqq
qq
57j
:read footer.txt
3j
@q
q
```

Note that the register to which you record the macro must be cleared (`qqq`) and that you must not use tab-completion when reading the footer-file (`:read footer.txt`).

You can then use the macro (normal mode):

```
@q
```